# Blender render "splits" frame in two parts

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a strange problem rendering Blender. In the Viewport Shading everything is fine, but when I render in cycles, the frame "splits" into two parts, and it seems that above it renders in CUDA, while below in OptiX (which is the Render Device I am using). I have a GTX1050Ti and a Ryzen 7 3800X. Thank you[image: OptiX Cycles render] [image: Viewport Shading using OptiX]

Comment: You posted a rendered image above and a viewport image below. Where is the spliting? I can't see anything strange, what do we looking for?

Comment: Are you referring to the fence?

Comment: @CameronCritchlow yes